# C# DLL Interop: native function receives different value of parameter than what it was called with from C#

Tags: c#, c++, interop

I have a problem, I'm doing some C#<->C++ interop via a C interface and I have a function that I import from a dll like this

```cs
[DllImport("pixi_api", EntryPoint = "pixi_sprite_asm_file", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.CustomMarshaler, MarshalTypeRef = typeof(PixiStringMarshaler))]
private static extern pixi_string _pixi_sprite_asm_file(IntPtr sprite);
```

and it gets called, for example, like this

```cs
var cstr = _pixi_sprite_asm_file(data_pointer);
```

the actual function in the DLL looks like this

```cpp
EXPORT pixi_string pixi_sprite_asm_file(pixi_sprite_t pixi_sprite_ptr) {
    const char* const ptr = pixi_sprite_ptr->asm_file;
    pixi_string str = {ptr, static_cast<int>(strlen(ptr))};
    return str;
}
```

however there's a problem:
if I print the data_pointer passed from the C# code, before the call to _pixi_sprite_asm_file and then I print it while inside the c native function call (the pixi_sprite_ptr), I get 2 completely different pointers and as such, everything explodes.

e.g:
data_pointer =>  191BF4A0300

pixi_sprite_ptr => 0x00007ffc0e1ebb92

I have other methods that return simple-to-marshal types such as ints, that don't have this problem and the pointer gets passed unchanged.
e.g this one works, the pointers are the same and it returns the expected value:

```cs
[DllImport("pixi_api", EntryPoint = "pixi_sprite_line", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
private static extern int _pixi_sprite_line(IntPtr sprite);
```

I have no clue what could be going wrong.

[An example of what it looks like when called](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1COfq.gif)

Comment: You misinterpret what happens, the debugger did *not* step into the native code.  The next code it shows beyond the call is still C#, the custom marshaller that you used to convert the return value of the native function.  It runs after the native code is complete. 
 Of course that is a completely different pointer, it created a new pixi_string object.  We can't see that marshaller or verify that it might be a dangling pointer.

Comment: Why would the marshaller have anything to do with the passed-in value, it's only for the return. The access violation exception happens in the native code (strlen() call) because the pointer passed to the native function is different. I don't see why the custom marshaller would interfere there. In fact, even if I comment out the whole custom marshalling of the return type, it still blows up in the same spot

Comment: The proof that it, in fact, does step into the native code, is [here](https://imgur.com/NQHPClE), I'm expecting the data_pointer and pixi_sprite_ptr to have the same value but they aren't. Again, this is without any custom marshalling shenanigans.

Comment: What data type is `pixi_string` in C# and in C++?

Comment: If you are able to add new wrapper functions to the native side, you will have much more luck using `SysAllocStringByteLen` and returning a `BSTR` which p/invoke already knows how to marshal.

Comment: I fixed this.
The issue was that I was returning a struct by value from C code, which, in itself shouldn't be an issue, however the C# interop can't deal with it, probably due to some strange calling conventions (even thought everything was marked cdecl and the compiler gave me no warnings at all, which was weird) some registers were being trampled and the value was being read from the wrong thing. I'm now returning a pointer and that works perfectly. I'm not sure how to mark a question as solved, but this is indeed fixed.